# How to remove 1px blank / dead pixel on the right side of the 12th column in a fluid grid

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

When 8 columns are floated next to 4 columns to form the full 12 columns of the container, there is a small dead pixel on the right that appears and reappears as you scale the browser. This seems to be due to rounding and decimal place issues.

The grid this is on is a custom fluid grid created by a different front end dev.  It appears and disappears as you drag the window. Occasionally it's there, sometimes it's not.

I've looked into altering the % of this grid and it simply does not resolve this issue. Any ideas?

Here is an example of a custom grid which was generated for me by a tool. Using these numbers does not fix the 1px issue.

```
Span 1:    8.33333333333%
Span 2:    16.6666666667%
Span 3:    25.0%
Span 4:    33.3333333333%
Span 5:    41.6666666667%
Span 6:    50.0%
Span 7:    58.3333333333%
Span 8:    66.6666666667%
Span 9:    75.0%
Span 10:    83.3333333333%
Span 11:    91.6666666667%
Span 12:    100%
```

Comment: Since this is a responsive grid, it the dead space in the narrow or wide layout? Approximately how wide a broswer windows do I need to replacie the issue?

Comment: maybe because 66.666+33.333=99.999% not 100.

Comment: @ScottRickman as you scale to different sizes above container width it will disappear and appear.

Comment: @jeromeM correct but I set the right values (to the outermost decimal points) and it still doesn't fix it. The other thing to consider is that a grid_8 might be sometimes with a grid_2 and a grid_2 so I can't just hardcode grid_8 to have an extra decimal, nor can I hardcode grid_4 to have an extra decimal. I'm not sure exactly how to fix this grid.

Comment: You can set a `float: right` to the right column.

Comment: Make grid_8 67% and grid_4 33%, that way no rounding errors to contend with?

Comment: @ScottRickman that doesn't fix the overall grid though. there are other combinations which will break as a result of doing that. for example grid_8 and grid_2 and grid_2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jeromeM's answer was correct. I pulled this from Foundation:

```
[class*="column"] + [class*="column"]:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

The last column should always be floated right to resolve this issue. The 1 pixel will be taken care of by the last column floating right.